# How to resolve invalid issue in template driven form angular 8

Tags: typescript, angular8

In template driven form i am getting below the error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'invalid' of undefined
```

I do not know why i am getting this.How to resolve this issue?

app.component.html:

```
<form name="form" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && onSubmit()" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="categoryName">Category Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="categoryName" [(ngModel)]="cate.categoryName" minlength="5" #categoryname="ngModel" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': f.submitted && categoryName.invalid }" required/>
                <div *ngIf="f.submitted && categoryName.invalid" class="invalid-feedback">
                    <div *ngIf="categoryName.errors.required">
                        Category Name is required
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="categoryName?.touched && categoryName?.errors.minlength" class="invalid-feedback">
                    Category Name must be at least 5 characters long.
                </div>
            </div>
</form>
```

app.component.ts:

```
  cate: any = {}; 
  onSubmit() {
      alert(this.cate.categoryName);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your template:

```
categoryName.invalid
```

But I can't see any place where categoryName is set to something.

You could "fix" it like so

```
 categoryName?.invalid
```

Note that `#categoryname` and categoryName are not the same (lower case vs upper case "n").

Comment: Ok..Thank you so much

Comment: But some time i am getting ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'minlength' of null

Comment: This part `categoryName?.errors.minlength` will throw this error if categoryName is set but its error property has value null. You can solve it the same way by writing `categoryName?.errors?.minlength